# Как оптимально можно обойти ошибку : ORA-01489: результат строковой конкатенации слишком велик?

Tags: sql, oracle

На данный момент имею следующую структуру данных таблиц [таблицы с запросом](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=39e4132f02ac9442d4d2a532a44d96db).

Конкатенирую значения колонок следующим образом:

```
select 
    a, b, id, listagg (tst, ' ') within group (order by num asc) res
from one t1
join two t2 on t2.dat = t1.dat
group by a, b, id
```

На реальных данных сталкиваюсь со следущей ошибкой:

> SQL Error [1489] [72000]: ORA-01489: результат строковой конкатенации слишком велик

Подсказжите, как оптимально можно обойти эту ошибку и выполнить конкатенацию?

---

Результат не желательно обрезать, желательно сохранять результат полного склеивания.
В данном случае, скорость обработки не играет роли, важно сохранить целостность склеивания строк.

Comment: А какая версия БД у вас?

Comment: @0xdb версия 12.0.1

Comment: Чтобы эффективно обойти ощибку, ещё уточнение: а что ожидается, обрезать результат или нет; главный критерий скорость или простота, т.е. экономия на разработку.

Comment: Нет, результата не желательно обрезать, желательно сохранять результат полного склеивания, в данном случае скорость обработки не играет роль важно сохранить целостность склеивания строк

Comment: Благодарю, буду пробовать!))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> в данном случае скорость обработки не играет роль важно сохранить целостность склеивания строк

В этом случае подойдёт функция `XMLAgg`, которая может работать с типом данных `CLOB`, то есть длина результата практически не ограничена. Неоспоримое преимушество решения - простота, на изменение запроса потратил менее 1 минуты.

Воспроизводимый пример с тестовыми данными из вопроса ([db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e7c48f71eea716a65c60d891d4eeef85)):

```
select a, b, id, rtrim (
    xmlAgg (xmlElement (e, tst, ' ')
        .extract ('//text()') order by num).getClobVal ()) res
from one t1
join two t2 on t2.dat = t1.dat
group by a, b, id
```